# Why am I getting this Transform error in my iOS simulator?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

At first, I was using `Expo` to run my projects on my physical device which means that it doesn't come with an `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` files upon creating a project (All you get is an `App.js` file which is equivalent to the aforementioned files).

I then copy and pasted my files/code into a normal `React Native` project (not `Expo`) which means now I do have `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` files.  Specifically, I copy & pasted whatever's in `App.js` into `index.ios.js` hoping it carries out the same functionality.

I have no idea why it's throwing this me error upon hitting `Run` to see what will show up on my `iOS` simulator.

Picture of error included below.

[Transform Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O85aH.png)

Here's `index.ios.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import {Navigator} from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';
import BackGround from './components/BackGround';
import Login from "./components/Login";
import CreateAccount from "./components/CreateAccount";

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.back}>
              <BackGround/>
              <Navigator
                  initialRoute={{id: 'Login'}}
                  renderScene={this.navigatorRenderScene}
              />
            </View>
        );
    }

    navigatorRenderScene() {
        _navigator = _navigator;
        switch(route.id) {
            case 'Login':
                return (<Login navigator={navigator} title="Login"/>);
            case 'CreateAccount':
                return (<CreateAccount navigator={navigator} title="Create Account" />);
        }
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    back: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Here's `BackGround.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Image, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import Login from './Login';

class BackGround extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.first}>
                <Image style={styles.container} source={require('../pictures/smoke.jpg')}>
                    <View style={styles.second}>
                        <View style={styles.movementTitle}>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>Dendro</Text>
                        </View>
                        <Login/>
                    </View>
                </Image>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        width: null,
        height: null,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    },

    first: {
        flex: 1
    },

    second: {
       paddingTop: 290 // Moves both <TextInput> boxes down.
    },

    title: {
        fontSize: 34,
        textAlign: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        fontFamily: 'Bodoni 72'
    }

    // movementTitle: {
    //     paddingBottom: 34
    // }
});

export default BackGround;
```

Here's `CreateAccount.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

class CreateAccount extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Text>Must get to this page</Text>
        );
    }
}

export default CreateAccount;
```

Here's `Login.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';

class Login extends Component {
    onButtonPress() {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            id: 'Create Account'
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={"padding"} style={styles.container}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        returnKeyType={"next"}
                        keyboardType={"email-address"}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        placeholder={"Email"}
                    />

                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        returnKeyType={"go"}
                        placeholder={"Password"}
                        secureTextEntry
                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity>
                        <Text style={styles.loginAndCA}>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
                        <Text style={styles.loginAndCA}>Create Account</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        padding: 20 // Length of text input boxes.
    },

    input: {
        backgroundColor: '#DAE5FF',
        padding: 20,
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        marginBottom: 10,
        borderRadius: 15
    },

    loginAndCA: {
        fontSize: 40,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white',
        fontFamily: 'Bodoni 72 Smallcaps',
        paddingHorizontal: 10
    }
});

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use standard React-Native you need to register your app with 
[`AppRegistry`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html).

If you create a new project `react-native-init test` and view the `index.ios.js` or `index.android.js` files, you will see the below code at the bottom of the file.

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('test', () => test);
```